# Will relationship be removed by setting the foreign key to 0?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In Entity Framework, will the following code remove a relationship by setting the foreign key to 0?

`entity.relationEntityID = 0;`

Comment: I think you've to set `null`, but not `0`.  Because `0` is still integer value and there is no entity with such Id.

Answer (score 0):

It will search related entity with `id` equals `0`, and return an error if will not find any, to remove relation you should make field nullable and set it to `null`.